# NSManagedObject custom accessors / get

Tags: objective-c, core-data, dynamic

I have two objects, forms and customers. A job has forms a form can have child forms. What I'd like to do is, because the form relationship is recursive and only the top form has the relationship to the job, in my `Form` `NSManagedObject` I'd like to return the topmost 'parentForm.job' if self.job is nil.

```
import "Form.h"
import "Job.h"

@implementation Form

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
```

Usually in non managed objects I'd do

```
-(Job *)job
{
    if (!_job && self.parentForm)
        return self.parentForm.job;

    return _job;
}
```

But alas no _properties due to being dynamic... Obviously I can't do this

```
-(Job *)job
{
    if (!self.job && self.parentForm)
        return self.parentForm.job;

    return self.job;
}
```

How do I create an accessor for dynamic properties in this instance?
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You have to use the primitive accessors.  See `primitiveValueForKey:`.

Comment: Thanks Avi. I'll write an answer below for posterity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from Avi's comment

```
-(Job *)job
{
    Job *job = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"job"];

    if (!job && self.parentForm)
        return self.parentForm.job;

    return job;
}
```